# c# overriding operator in MyString class returns the same object

Tags: c#, string, overriding

I want to override -- operator for MyString class. It should find the shortest word in string. Here is code:

```
class MyString
{
    private string data;
    public string Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    public MyString(string s)
    {
        Data = s;
    }

    public MyString(MyString s)
    {
        Data = s.Data;
    }

    public static MyString operator --(MyString s)
    {
        var words = s.Data.Split();
        int l = 99999, ind = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            if (words[i].Length < l)
            {
                ind = i;
                l = words[i].Length;
            }
        }
        MyString result = new MyString(words[ind]);
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I try to use it like this:

```
    MyString s1, shortest;
    s1 = new MyString("one two three");
    shortest = s1--;
    Console.WriteLine(shortest.Data);
```

it returns "one two three" instead of "one". How can I fix it?

Comment: that's a **horrible** use of the `--` operator, btw

Comment: For the love of god don't do this.  Why would anyone know to use that operator which has nothing to do with what you want it to do?  Also, if your goal is to _"find the shortest word in string"_ write a method called `FindTheShortestWord()` and use that

Comment: I know but task says to use it

Comment: @st_dec if a school gave you that task, get your money back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var x = foo--;
```

is **post**-decrement, i.e. similar to:

```
var x = foo;
foo--;
```

You *might* want **pre**-decrement, i.e.

```
var x = --foo;
```

which is similar to:

```
foo--;
var x = foo;
```

Either way: it inappropriately changes `foo`, which you probably don't want. If you do:

```
shortest = --s1;
Console.WriteLine(shortest.Data);
Console.WriteLine(s1.Data);
```

You'll see that `s1.Data` is **also** now `"one"`.

I suggest instead:

```
shortest = s1.GetShortestWord();
Console.WriteLine(shortest.Data);
```